# Need Shell functions replacement for conditions

Tags: shell

I am very new to shell scripting and i need to write a script, the conditions are pretty straight fwd:

i have 2 dir location

First Dir:
$ABC_123/cert

which contains 3 files:

file1.pem
file2.pem
file3.pem

Second Dir:
$ABC_123/private

which contains 2 files:

file4.pem
file5.pem

these files needs to be replaced/appended with files from a user input dir location depending on below conditions

1. if file3 is present in the user input dir location then take back of all files under the above two dir and then replace file1,file2,file4,file5 and append file3
2. if file3 is not present in the user input dir location then take back up and replace only file 1,file2,file4,file5 only

i want to write a shell function for back up and replace/append conditions.

Below is the shell i wrote:

```
    #!/bin/sh

$ABC_123=/ABC/123/XCOM
export ABC_123

# input the change number
    printf 'Enter the NUMBER number\n'
    read NUMBER
    

file1="$ABC_123/certs/fil2cert.pem"
file2="$ABC_123/certs/fil2cert.pem"
file3="$ABC_123/certs/fil3cert.pem"
file4="$ABC_123/private/fil4key.pem"
file5="$ABC_123/private/fil5key.pem"
file6="$ABC_123/private/fil6key.pem"
file7="/tmp/$NUMBER/fil3cert.pem"

    
   # Begining of the implementation
 if [ -f $file1 ] && [ -f $file2 ] && [ -f $file3 ] && [ -f $file4 ] && [ -f $file5 ] && [ ! -f $file6 ] && [ -f $file7 ]

then

     
#
#BACKUP
#
        cp -p $file1 $file1.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp
        cp -p $file2 $file2.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp
        cp -p $file3 $file3.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp
        cp -p $file4 $file4.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp
        cp -p $file5 $file5.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp

#
#REPLACE
#
        cp /tmp/$NUMBER/*key.pem $ABC_123/private/
        cp /tmp/$NUMBER/*cert.pem $ABC_123/certs/
        cat /tmp/$NUMBER/fil3cert.pem >> $ABC_123/certs/fil3cert.pem
        

#
#CHANGE PERMISSIONS
#
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/private/*key.pem
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/certs/*cert.pem
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/certs/fil3cert.pem

        chown root:root $ABC_123/private/*key.pem
        chown root:root $ABC_123/certs/*cert.pem
        chown root:root $ABC_123/certs/fil3cert.pem



        
elif [ -f $file1 ] && [ -f $file2 ] && [ -f $file3 ] && [ -f $file4 ] && [ -f $file5 ] && [ ! -f $file6 ] && [ ! -f $file7 ]

then

   
#
#BACKUP
#
        cp -p $file1 $file1.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp
        cp -p $file2 $file2.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp
        cp -p $file3 $file3.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp
        cp -p $file4 $file4.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp

#
#REPLACE
#
        cp /tmp/$NUMBER/*key.pem $ABC_123/private/
        cp /tmp/$NUMBER/*cert.pem $ABC_123/certs/
        
        

#
#CHANGE PERMISSIONS
#
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/private/*key.pem
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/certs/*cert.pem
       

        chown root:root $ABC_123/private/*key.pem
        chown root:root $ABC_123/certs/*cert.pem
    

    

elif [ ! -f $file1 ] && [ ! -f $file2 ] && [ ! -f $file3 ] && [ ! -f $file4 ] && [ ! -f $file5 ] && [ ! -f $file6 ]

           then

#
#REPLACE
#
        cp /tmp/$NUMBER/*key.pem $ABC_123/private/
        cp /tmp/$NUMBER/*cert.pem $ABC_123/certs/
        cp /tmp/$NUMBER/fil3cert.pem $ABC_123/certs/

#
#CHANGE PERMISSIONS
#
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/private/*key.pem
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/certs/*cert.pem
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/certs/fil3cert.pem

        chown root:root $ABC_123/private/*key.pem
        chown root:root $ABC_123/certs/*cert.pem
        chown root:root $ABC_123/certs/fil3cert.pem


elif [ -f $file6 ]

   then
   
#
# BACKUP
#

        find $ABC_123/certs/* -type f -exec mv {} {}.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp \;
        find $ABC_123/private/* -type f -exec mv {} {}.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).bkp \;


#
# REPLACE
#
        cp /tmp/$NUMBER/*key.pem $ABC_123/private/
        cp /tmp/$NUMBER/*cert.pem $ABC_123/certs/
        cp /tmp/$NUMBER/fil3cert.pem $ABC_123/certs/

#
# CHANGE PERMISSIONS
#
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/private/*key.pem
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/certs/*cert.pem
        chmod 644 $ABC_123/certs/fil3cert.pem

        chown root:root $ABC_123/private/*key.pem
        chown root:root $ABC_123/certs/*cert.pem
        chown root:root $ABC_123/certs/fil3cert.pem



elif [ ! -f "$file1" ] || [ ! -f "$file2" ] || [ ! -f "$file3" ] || [ ! -f "$file4" ] || [ ! -f "$file5" ] && [ ! -f "$file6" ] ; then
    # At least one file is missing, writing the list of missing file(s):
    echo -n "Missing file(s): "
    for i in "$file1" "$file2" "$file3" "$file4" "$file5" ; do
        if [ ! -f "$i" ] ; then
            echo -n "$i "
        fi
    done
    echo
    
fi
```

i want to use shell function instead of repeating the BACKUP,REPLACEMENT and CHANGE PERMISSION command again and again

Comment: What's your exact question? Show the functions you wrote, and explain where the problem is.

Comment: I have updated my question with the query I wrote

Comment: Do I need to write 3 functions each for BACKUP,REPLACE and CHANGE PERMISSIONS?

Comment: In your question, you asked about a shell function for doing the **condition**, nor for the action afterwards. If you also want to factor out something else, please ask a new question (it is discouraged on Stackoverflow to discuss several topics in a single question).

Comment: Sure, I will start a new disccussion..

Answer (score 0):

Your shell function could be something like

```
all_present() {
  for file
  do
    [ -f $file ] || return 1
  done
  return 0
}
```

and it would be used like this:

```
if ! all_present "$file1" "$file2" "$file3" "$file4" "$file5" "$file6"
then
  echo at least one is missing
  ...
```

BTW: In case you can switch from shell to bash or zsh or ksh, you can hold all files in an array and the whole expression would be simpler.